# How can I create multiple Gemfile to run with different Ruby version with Uru?

Tags: ruby

How can I create multiple Gemfile to run with different Ruby version? I am using Uru to manage ruby versions and was wondering if we have something like create gemsets in RVM.
I want to be able to run a Gemfile for Ruby v1.8.7 and another for v2.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

I would discourage from creating multiple gemsets, it will be a maintenance mess (that probably accounts for gemsets for different rubys as well), also there is a clean way to manage multiple ruby versions within a Gemset (given that you are 100% sure that you only serve to those versions):

```
if Gem::Version.new('1.8.7') == Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION)
   # your gemspec for 1.8.7
else
   # your gemspec for 2.5.1
```

Using `Gemfile::Version` allows you to do version comparisons, for instance:

```
Gem::Version.new('1.8.7') < Gem::Version.new('2.5.1')
# => true
```

See the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks @wiesion. That helped but caused another issue. I was able to bundle install on v2.5.1 but it is failing on the other version, saying that it needs ruby >1.9. I am not sure what my gemfile path is set to how to update that for different projects.

Comment: It is trying to download concurrent-ruby 1.0.5 when i bundle install. The insrallation fails saying that it needs ruby >1.9. I do not have concurrent-ruby 1.0.5  in my gemfile but for some reason it is trying to install.